# Add heatmap to a layer in Folium

Tags: python, dictionary, folium

I have this sample code:

```
from glob import glob
import numpy as np
import folium
from folium import plugins
from folium.plugins import HeatMap

lon, lat = -86.276, 30.935 
zoom_start = 5


data = (
    np.random.normal(size=(100, 3)) *
    np.array([[1, 1, 1]]) +
    np.array([[48, 5, 1]])
).tolist()
m = folium.Map([48, 5], tiles='stamentoner', zoom_start=6)

HeatMap(data).add_to(m)
m
```

[image]

How can I add this heat map to a layer so I can hide it if needed?

Comment: Thank you for making this easy to reproduce

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would first add your HeatMap to a FeatureGroup and then add that FeatureGroup to the map(m). I would then add a LayerControl to your map (check the upper right corner).   Does this suffice?

```
from glob import glob
import numpy as np
import folium
from folium import plugins
from folium.plugins import HeatMap

lon, lat = -86.276, 30.935 
zoom_start = 5


data = (
    np.random.normal(size=(100, 3)) *
    np.array([[1, 1, 1]]) +
    np.array([[48, 5, 1]])
).tolist()
m = folium.Map([48, 5], tiles='stamentoner', zoom_start=6)

HeatMap(data).add_to(folium.FeatureGroup(name='Heat Map').add_to(m))
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m
```

[image]